# Html attribute based on server side variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have something like this.

```
<input type="text">
```

I want enable/disable it based in certain variable value in server side.

I have tried this.

```
<input type="text" <%= DisableServiceInfo ? "disabled":"" %>/>
```

but not working.

I know this can be done.

```
<input type="text" disabled="<%= DisableServiceInfo ? "disabled":"invalid value" %>"/>
```

but this is not a valid mark-up. Because the only **valid** way to enable control is to remove `disabled` attribute.

I am not asking how value can be supplied based on variable but how **attribute in injected**

Please don't answer the ways to set it server side or by javascript. I just want to know if it is possible in this way?

Comment: why not use a control?

Comment: You say that `<input type="text" <%= DisableServiceInfo ? "disabled":"" %>` does not work. It works for me (if `DisableServiceInfo` is a boolean property and if you add the closing tag).

Comment: What is the type of DisableServiceInfo?

Comment: @ShiranDror bool var

Answer (score 3):

Is this webforms? If you want to do this by the book, you can manually add an Id, and Runat="Server". Once you've done that, your control can be manipulated in your code-behind.

If your Id is ServiceInfo, you could do:

```
ServiceInfo.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

Comment: Sorry Mark, I just wanted to do it by this way only, just for learning, I know other ways too.